# Is there any way to use goto() without reloading page on SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, typescript, routes, sveltekit, goto

I have one problem: I need to add additional part to url (IE: I have /route and I need to convert it to /route/something without reloading of the page. I’ve tried to use goto(), but it reloads the page. I would be appreciate if someone could help me.

I'll excpect change url params ex: /watchlist/[lang] without reloading, if it possible, by using goto()

Comment: Is this based on user interaction? If not you could do a redirect before the page is even returned.

Answer (score 4):

For now, you should use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) instead of sveltekit goto() because goto() will actually navigate to the target page (trigger the load() ) while History API won't. See issue [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2673).

```
window.history.replaceState(history.state, '', newURL)
```

Two things to note:

1. Pass the current state as the first parameter in the replaceState() to avoid messing up sveltekit router.
2. Make sure you do have a route for the newURL so that a page refresh won't break your app.

Comment: Awesome thanks for this! I'm building an app right now where I want to change the params and routes on the clientside (the point is so that it's shareable), but not refresh the page and lose the state that's untracked by the url.

Answer (score 3):

SvelteKit uses a file system and path based router, so if you change the path, you invoke a page change. You probably should just *not* make something like the language part of the path.

You could for example pass it as a query parameter or store it in a cookie, storage or server-side with session/user information.

To change the query, you can do something like this:

```js
function onChange() {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    url.searchParams.set('lang', 'en');

    goto(url.href);
    // or this, if you do not want a new history entry:
    goto(url.href, { replaceState: true });
}
```

If you really want to prevent navigation and keep it in the path you could try using `history.pushState`/`history.pushState`, but this could potentially mess up the navigation as this circumvents the SvelteKit router. There also should be a route for whatever you set the URL to, otherwise a page reload will cause an error as the page will no longer be found.